# I need help/tips for solving this equation: $x^3+3x^2+x+1=0$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this equation:

$x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1 = 0$

I tried to guess a root so I could try polinomial division to try factorise this equation but I couldn't find any whole integers for that. I thought of maybe using variable substitution but I dont think that would work here.

Any tips/explained solution on how to solve an equation like this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use the formula for the roots of a cubic equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots

Comment: It has one real root near -2.7693 and two complex roots. You just have to use the standard formulae.

Comment: The $3$ is deliberate, as an integer change makes a "depressed" cubic, no zero term. Take $x = t-1,$ you get $t^3 + pt + q$ for integers $p,q,$ no $t^2$ term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfy says one real, two complex roots,
so you are out of luck
if you want a simple solution.

The real root is,
after some reformatting,

$ -1-\dfrac{(9-\sqrt{57})^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\dfrac{2}{(3 (9-\sqrt{57}))^{1/3}}
$